# Display busy cursor while processing queries

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've been searching for this and couldn't find something that works as I'd want it to. I have a classic asp.net webpage which makes a lot of SQL queries, some longer than others. I am not very familiar with terms to use, but the page doesn't load on each commands. So let's say the user fills some fields, then presses "Submit", it looks like nothing is happening even though SQL is processing a query.

I am looking for a way to let the user know a process is going on (busy/wait/hourglass cursor is enough for me). I tried some JavaScript calls on onbeforeunload and onunload events but as I said, page doesn't "reload" once the user did an action on it. I tried to look for the same for postbacks, but I couldn't find much and I'm not even sure postback is what is happening.

Any help with what to look for would be appreciated. As it is right now and with my limited understanding of how things work in a asp.net webpage, I'm not sure what to search for anymore.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using MVC or classic asp.net? So user presses button, and fires an event to call said query?. Does the button click event cause a postback?

Comment: It is a classic asp.net page, I should've mentioned. When the user presses a button, it will call the button's function which then calls the right methods that proceed to do the sql queries to my SQL server. I'm not sure about the postback. I didn't add anything that I know of to cause a postback, so I'd say it's at its default state?

Comment: You're gonna have to post some of your code

Comment: I've found a workaround using the <asp:UpdateProgress> and <ProgressTemplate> which displays an image over the screen during the loading times. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this if your using classic ASP.NET

Create a JS function

```
function doHourglass()
{
  document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
}
```

Add these two events on your Body Tag. If your using an update panel add them to the update panel tag instead

```
<body onbeforeunload="doHourglass();" onunload="doHourglass();">
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8243/Hourglass-cursor-for-Web-ASP-NET-pages